# My app starts automatically in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am developing an application and I have no service in it and just have push notification. When I install my app in android 7 it will automatically start every second and if I push back button it will close and open again.

What is the problem?

I test it in android 4.4.2 and 5.0.1 it work fine.
I finish all my activities after I push back button and no activity is run after I finish first activity.
and if it did not run and after some minutes if I were searching in my menu it will starts suddenly and I became crazy because of it.

in back button I wrote this code to finish my app:

```
 this.finish();
 System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Your manifest file and how you handle the push notification etc.

Comment: This is interesting. When it starts back up, does it start with your MainActivity or it opens up any activity that was closed last? Can you post the code of your MainActivity and where you invoke your PushNotification?